# select rows from selected rows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i have following procedure syntax working :

```
select count(1) from
from
(
  select id,
  CASE
  when a >= 0 and a <= 30 then 'one'    
  when a >= 31 and a <= 60  then 'two'    
  when a >= 61 and a <= 90  then 'three'    
  else 'NO'
  END
  FROM tabel_1 t
  Where
  (
        (
           TO_CHAR(t.aDate, 'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(pFrom_Date, 'YYYYMMDD') AND    
                TO_CHAR(pTo_Date, 'YYYYMMDD')                    
                                                                 //cond1
        ) OR
        (
           TO_CHAR(t.bDate, 'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(pFrom_Date, 'YYYYMMDD') AND    
                TO_CHAR(pTo_Date, 'YYYYMMDD')                                                      
                                                                 //cond2
        )OR
        (
           TO_CHAR(t.bDate, 'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(pFrom_Date, 'YYYYMMDD') AND    
                TO_CHAR(pTo_Date, 'YYYYMMDD')                                                      
                                                                 //cond3
        )

        AND

        (
              p_Type = 'Admin' AND
                            t.ID > 0    //condA
        )OR
        < 0
        (
          SELECT COUNT(1)
                            FROM tab_2 t2
                            WHERE t2.ID = USER_ID AND
                                  t.ID = t2.ID              condB
        )
   )
  )


)
```

### I mean that following clause

```
     Where
     ( (
                  (
              TO_CHAR(t.aDate, 'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(pFrom_Date, 'YYYYMMDD') AND    


              TO_CHAR(pTo_Date, 'YYYYMMDD')                    
                                                             //cond1
                ) OR
                (
                   TO_CHAR(t.bDate, 'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(pFrom_Date, 'YYYYMMDD')              

                   AND

                        TO_CHAR(pTo_Date, 'YYYYMMDD')                                                      
                                                             //cond2
                )OR
                (
                   TO_CHAR(t.bDate, 'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(pFrom_Date, 'YYYYMMDD') 

                    AND    
                        TO_CHAR(pTo_Date, 'YYYYMMDD')                                                      
                                                             //cond3
                ) )
```

### **should only work for**

```
                       ( (
                        p_Type = 'Admin' AND
                        t.ID > 0    //condA
                       )OR
                         < 0
                       (
                             SELECT COUNT(1)
                             FROM tab_2 t2
                              WHERE t2.ID = USER_ID AND
                              t.ID = t2.ID              condB
                        ) )
```

---

//p_type is a varchar which has some value to be comapred. and USER_ID is a int which holds a integer value.
i want cond1 OR con2 OR con3 to be worked only for condA OR condB..
i mean i want this result to be displayed only for admin or matched user id for id of tab_2.
 i think this is not the correct one. because it work for both OR statements .
can anyone plz help.. thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your sub-query is doing at the moment is:

```
cond1 OR cond2 OR (cond3 AND condA) OR condB
```

That is, it will be true if either cond1, cond2 or condB is true or where cond3 and condA are both true.

But what I think you want is:

```
(cond1 OR cond2 OR cond3) AND (condA OR condB)
```

Where it is only true if any of cond1, cond2 or cond3 is true and any of condA or condB is true.

If that is the case then you need to put brackets around the first 3 conds and around the last two:

```
select count(1) from
from
(
  select id,
  CASE
  when a >= 0 and a <= 30 then 'one'    
  when a >= 31 and a <= 60  then 'two'    
  when a >= 61 and a <= 90  then 'three'    
  else 'NO'
  END
  FROM tabel_1 t
  Where
  ( (
        (
           TO_CHAR(t.aDate, 'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(pFrom_Date, 'YYYYMMDD') AND    
                TO_CHAR(pTo_Date, 'YYYYMMDD')                    
                                                                 //cond1
        ) OR
        (
           TO_CHAR(t.bDate, 'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(pFrom_Date, 'YYYYMMDD') AND    
                TO_CHAR(pTo_Date, 'YYYYMMDD')                                                      
                                                                 //cond2
        )OR
        (
           TO_CHAR(t.bDate, 'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(pFrom_Date, 'YYYYMMDD') AND    
                TO_CHAR(pTo_Date, 'YYYYMMDD')                                                      
                                                                 //cond3
        ) )

        AND

        ( (
              p_Type = 'Admin' AND
                            t.ID > 0    //condA
        )OR
        < 0
        (
          SELECT COUNT(1)
                            FROM tab_2 t2
                            WHERE t2.ID = USER_ID AND
                                  t.ID = t2.ID              condB
        ) )
   )
  )


)
```

Comment: thanx for the reply. See what condA and CondB should do is they are the key factor. they are checking weather user is verified (weather admin or assigned user) . if user is verified than only this case result should print with its filter of dates.

Comment: your comment is not clear to me, it seams that you want: (condA AND (cond1 OR cond2 OR cond3)) OR (condB AND (cond1 OR cond2 OR cond3)) which is equivalent to @John Doyle answer

Comment: see for example. condA is for admin and condB is for normal user who is assigned some work. and cond1, cond2, cond3 is for output that i want for authorized person, (could be admin or valid user). so i want that main result to be only shown for admin and valid user. i want to check wheather user loginID is valid to get this as a result